# How do I debug in visual studio code a python program that calls c functions in a shared library from a f2py interface

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, f2py

I have currently an issue with debugging with visual studio code . I want to attach GDB to a C (.so) shared library module that is called via a main python program that interfaces with the C shared library with F2PY.

How do I procede to create a launch configuration in vscode for gdb to debug that C shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-language debugging from Python to C is only available in Visual Studio, not in VS Code.